# Finding probability involving two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we are given two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}\mathrm e^{-x} &:& 0 < y < x < \infty \\ 0 &:&\textrm{else}
\end{cases}$$

How come $P(6<X\leq 7 \mid Y=4) = \int_{6}^{7}f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 4)\,\mathrm dx$?

I know that if we have something like $P(6<X\leq7 )$, it can be found using $\int_{6}^{7}f_{X}(x)\,\mathrm dx$, but how does the above work and makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the marginal density

$$f_Y(y)=\int_y^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=e^{-y}$$

Thus by definition

$$f_{X|Y}=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=e^y e^{-x}$$

Concluding

$$P(6<X<7|Y=4)=e^4\int_6^7 e^{-x}dx=e^{-2}-e^{-3}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how to calculate the above, but I am just confused about the logic behind what I have wrote. How does it ($P(6<X\leq7 | Y=4) = \int_{6}^{7}f_{X|Y}(x|y=4)dx$) makes sense?

Comment: user62487108: because I calculated the conditional density $f_{X|Y}$ and after this you can calculate any probability. In fact you can verify that $e^y e^{-x}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(x>y)}$ is a valid density

Comment: (1.) The probability of $\{6<X\leqslant 7\}$ is the integral of the marginal probability density of $X$ over the domain $\{6<x\leqslant 7\}$. .... and likewise (2.) The probability of $\{6<X\leqslant 7\}$ under condition that $Y=4$, is the integral of the *conditional* probability density of $X$ given $Y=4$ over the domain $\{6<x\leqslant 7\}$.   If it is sensible for 1. then it is sensible for 2. (With the proviso that the conditional probability density function does exist; which, as Tommik notes, you can verify that it does.)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(6<X\leqslant 7\mid Y=4) &=\lim\limits_{0<h\to 0}\dfrac{\mathsf P(6<X\leqslant 7, 4\leqslant Y<4+h)}{\mathsf P(4\leqslant Y<4+h)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\int_6^7 f_{X,Y}(x,4)\,\mathrm d x}{f_Y(4)}\\[1ex]&=\int_6^7 f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 4)\,\mathrm d x\\[4ex]&=\dfrac{\int_6^7 f_{X,Y}(x,4)\,\mathrm d x}{\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,4)\,\mathrm d x}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\int_6^7\mathrm  e^{-x}\,\mathrm d x}{\int_4^\infty \mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm d x}\\[1ex]&=(\mathrm e^{-6}-\mathrm e^{-7})\div\mathrm e^{-4}\\[1ex]&=\mathrm e^{-2}-\mathrm e^{-3}\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$